# VK API - return city names in latin

Tags: api, vk, latin

I am using [VK API](https://vk.com/dev/database.getCities) to get list of cities in specific country. Does anyone know how to show Russian cities (which are in Cyrilic) in Latin?
Example of JSON response:

> http://api.vk.com/method/places.getCities?lang=en&country_id=1&count=1000&need_all=1

I am trying to check if city exists, but if someone enter city name in latin, in some cases city check works, for example Vladivostok is Владивосток, but Moscow is Москва.

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution that works for me: firstly get all cities ids by places.getCities (database.getCities) method and then use database.getCitiesById providing saved cities ids like following:

```
database.getCitiesById?lang=en&city_ids=1,2,123
```

In request to this API method you can specify needed language by parameter "lang" (e.g. lang=en) and up to 1k comma-separated cities ids (e.g. city_ids=1,2,123,...).

database.getCitiesById [official documentation](https://new.vk.com/dev/database.getCitiesById)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can get the static list of Russian cities [here](https://github.com/stepanovmax/towns-russia). This JSON array contains the slug name of each city in English. It's a free list, so anyone can edit and add correct information for any localities.